# Remove item from cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3

Ok, I'm getting pretty crazy here. I'm trying to remove a variant from the cart. Adding works fine, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="purchasableId" value="{{ variant.id }}" id="{{ variant.sku }}">
<input type="submit">
```

(variant is an item from product.variants)

However, when I want to remove an item, I do it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lineItems[{{ variant.id }}][qty]" value="0">
<input type="submit">
```

But nothing gets removed. The weird thing is, when I query for lineItems, there's an item with the id "92". The id from the variant is `19874`. So that's the id I use in the hidden qty field. I have absolutely no idea where this `92` comes from. It is not the variant id. It's alo snot the product id. I don't know what it is. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a line item by including a remove parameter in the request. This example adds a checkbox the customer can use to remove the line item from the cart:

```
{% set cart = craft.commerce.carts.cart %}
<form method="post">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('commerce/cart/update-cart') }}
    {% for item in cart.lineItems %}
        <input type="number" name="lineItems[{{ item.id }}][qty]" min="1" value="{{ item.qty }}">
        <input type="text" name="lineItems[{{ item.id }}][note]" placeholder="My Note" value="{{ item.note }}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lineItems[{{ item.id }}][remove]" value="1"> Remove item<br>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Update Line Item</button>
</form>
```

You can check more on this on craft commerce documentation by using below link.
https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/orders-carts.html#carts

Comment: Thank you. Yes I found that in the docs. But that still means I need the lineItem ID for the item I want to remove. And I don't know that id, since I am on a product detail page and want to remove only that product. On the product page I only know the variant properties.

I could loop through all the lineItems and filter out the lineItem where the purchasableId = the variant id. But that doesn't sound like it is the best option there is. There must be something easier, no?